When running python with graalvm (Graalpy) can line numbers be included in errors
I am using python as a scripting language within java using graalvm but when the python script has errors the line number of the error is not reported.
For example the following fails with the message SyntaxError: expected ':' but does not include line number
 package interop;

 import org.graalvm.polyglot.*;

 class App {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         try (var context = Context.create()) {
             context.eval("python", "print()\nprint()\ndef error()");
         }
     }
 }

I have tried creating the Source instance in different ways and also running the graalpy-eval-demo
Does graalpy support including line numbers in error messages?

Here is how to get source error location
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (
            Engine engine = Engine.newBuilder()
                    .option("engine.WarnInterpreterOnly", "false")
                    .build();
            Context context = Context
                    .newBuilder("python")
                    .engine(engine)
                    .build()) {
        File file = new File("Hello.py");
        Source source = Source.newBuilder("python", file).build();
        context.eval(source);
    } catch (PolyglotException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        SourceSection s = e.getSourceLocation();
        int line = s.getStartLine();
        int col = s.getStartColumn();
        System.out.println("line:" + line + " col:" + col + " Err:" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

example python error prone code
ages = {
    'pam': 24,
    'jim': 24
    'michael': 43
}

print(f'Michael is {ages["michael"]} years old.')

error output in my local
[INFO] --- exec:3.1.1:exec (default-cli) @ eval_graalpy ---
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
        at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:402)
        at com.oracle.example.graalpy.Main.main(Main.java:25)
line:3 col:12 Err:SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?

You can find running example here. While doing some tests sometimes I saw that this approach may not reveal the exact line and I saw others had similar issues. You may need to create an issue on github for those.
